# Find high current latch or use Darlington array?

Tags: microcontroller, latch, led-matrix, darlington

Looking for best practices here. I'm building a common-anode LED matrix. I've got a current sink LED driver, and I'm looking for a latch that will provide enough current to drive an array of LEDs. All the latches I can find have very low current ratings. [This](http://adventuresinelectronics.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/my-led-matrix-needs-little-tlc.html?m=1) guy had some success with running high current latches in parallel to provide the current, but it seems sloppy and is definitely expensive. I am leaning towards trying a low current latch with a Darlington array, however I've never used one before and don't know what exactly I'm looking for. Can anyone tell me if that's a good way to go about it, and suggest an 8 bit latch and Darlington array combo? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "latch", are you talking about a digital latch such as D-latch, RS-latch, etc? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I'm sorry I was unclear. I meant a latched source driver.

Comment: How much current do you need per LED? (20 mA or 20 A or somewhere in between?)

Comment: Not sure at this stage, the LED matrices i bought haven't arrived yet and they did not have a data sheet. Let's assume 20mA per LED, and 32 columns, around 0.64 A at any one time, with only one channel open at a time (walking bit).

Comment: so you mean a shift register with latched outputs, which can source/sink a large amount of current?

Comment: Precisely. Just having trouble finding a configuration that sounds like it should work neatly.

Comment: When I searched for "latched source driver", the first hit was a Maxim part with 500 mA per output capability. I'm assuming when you say "all the latches I can find have very low current ratings", it means you need a lot more than 500 mA. Knowing what you need is absolutely necessary to be able to give you a recommendation.

Comment: Surely I'd want a maximum collected current rating around 1A if my estimated maximum current draw is 640 mA? Sorry if my ignorance is annoying.

Comment: You're not going to connect all of the LEDs to just one driver output, are you?

Comment: No, I'd have each row connected to a channel on the driver, and then each column connected to a channel on the current sink.